# Typescript: mark certain properties as optional

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for something that can do this:

```
type MakeOptional<T, U> = /* ... */;

interface A {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: Date;
}

type AWithOptionalFoo = MakeOptional<A, 'foo'>;
// result should be { foo?: string | undefined; bar: number; baz: number; }

type AWithOptionalBarAndBaz = MakeOptional<A, 'foo' | 'baz'>;
// result should be { foo?: string | undefined; bar: number; baz?: Date | undefined; }
```

This is what I've tried...

```
type MakeOptional<T, U> = { [P in keyof T]: P extends U ? T[P] | undefined : T[P] }
```

...which sort of works but it marks those properties as `T | undefined` instead of `(optional)? T | undefined`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Pick` type in combination with the `Exclude` type to get a type of the non-optional keys, then intersect that with a mapped type that makes the remainder optional (and unions them with `undefined`).

```
type MakeOptional<T, U extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, U>> & {
    [K in U]?: T[K] | undefined;
}
```

Or if you don't want the `undefined` union, you can just do the optional modifier:

```
type MakeOptional<T, U extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, U>> & Partial<Pick<T, U>>
```

Then, using either of those:

```
declare const test1: AWithOptionalFoo;
test1.foo // string | undefined
test1.bar // number
test1.baz // Date

// Note this is a misnomer, the type you defined for this uses "foo" and "baz".
declare const test2: AWithOptionalBarAndBaz;
test2.foo // string | undefined
test2.bar // number
test2.baz // Date | undefined
```